# ORDER BY and WITH(ROWLOCK, UPDLOCK, READPAST)

Tags: sql-server-2005, locking, sql-order-by

I need to set up a queue system using some SQL tables, like the one described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2177880/using-a-database-table-as-a-queue). That being, and since I need to filter queued items by different critera, inside a stored procedure I am using

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION

CREATE TABLE #Temp (ID INT, SOMEFIELD INT)

INSERT INTO #Temp SELECT TOP (@Something) TableA.ID, TableB.SomeField FROM TableA WITH (ROWLOCK, READPAST) INNER JOIN TableB WITH (UPDLOCK, READPAST) WHERE Condition1

INSERT INTO #Temp SELECT TOP (@Something) TableA.ID, TableB.SomeField FROM TableA WITH (ROWLOCK, READPAST) INNER JOIN TableB WITH (UPDLOCK, READPAST) WHERE Condition2

(...)

UPDATE TableB SET SomeField = 1 FROM TableB WITH (ROWLOCK, READPAST) WHERE ID IN (SELECT ID FROM #Temp)

COMMIT TRANSACTION
```

I am using `ROWLOCK` in the first table and `UPDLOCK` in the second because, after this select, I am going to update `TableB` only, though I need to make sure that these lines don't get updated in`TableA` by any other concurrent query. Everything goes well until the point where I need to insert an `ORDER BY` clause in any of the `SELECT`s above, so that only very specific  IDs get selected (I must really do this). What happens is:

1) Without `ORDER BY`, two concurrent executions execute as desired, returning different and non-overlapping results; however, they don't return the results I want because those precise results were outside the scope of every `SELECT` statement.

2) Using `ORDER BY` and two concurrent executions, only the first one returns results. The second one does not return anything.

I recall seeing on a blog that for these kind of queries with `WITH (ROWLOCK, READPAST)` and `ORDER BY` to work one needs to create indexes on the fields one is using in the ordering. I tried it, but I got the same results. How can I get past this problem?

**Edit:** For example, if I have a table `TestTable` with fields (TestID INT, Value INT) and values "(1,1), (2,2), ..." and execute "simultaneously"

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION

SELECT TOP 2 TestID FROM TestTable WITH (UPDLOCK, READPAST)

WAITFOR DELAY '00:00:05'

COMMIT TRANSACTION
```

the first execution returns lines (1,2) and the second one returns (3,4) as espected. However, if I execute

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION

SELECT TOP 2 TestID FROM TestTable WITH (UPDLOCK, READPAST) ORDER BY VALUE ASC

WAITFOR DELAY '00:00:05'

COMMIT TRANSACTION
```

the first one returns (1, 2) and the second returns nothing. Why is this?!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As expected

- The SELECT with the ORDER BY, without ROWLOCK, without index will have a table lock because of a scan/intermediate sort to work out TOP 2. So the 2nd session skips the whole table because of READPAST
- The SELECT without the ORDER BY is just picking any 2 rows, which happen to be in order of insert (pure coincidence, there is no implied order). The fact that these 2 rows are locked causes the 2nd session to skip to the next non-locked rows.

SQL Server attempts to keep locks as granular as possible but the scan means a table lock. Now, this wouldn't normally make a difference (it'd be a shared read lock) but you have UPDLOCK too which means an exclusively locked table

So, you need both of these

- 3 hints in the SELECT queries (ROWLOCK, UPDLOCK, READPAST) to control granularity, isolation and concurrency. 
   Using ROWLOCK only will still cause an exclusive lock on every row to scan/sort.
- an index on `Value` INCLUDE `TestID` to make the SELECT efficient. An index only will probably fix the concurrency but it won't be guaranteed.

In one of your previous questions I linked to my answer (in a comment) to [SQL Server Process Queue Race Condition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/939831/sql-server-process-queue-race-condition/940001#940001) where I have all 3 lock hints