# Order By with Multiple Joins

Tags: sql-server-2005

Since I can't post an answer to my [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6409945/please-help-me-with-inner-join-and-locks) yet, I decided to open a new post. To make things work with the code in that post, I had to add the hints `WITH ( ... , INDEX ( IX_REQUESTID ) )` and `WITH ( ... , INDEX ( IX_REQUESTIDREF ) )` to the tables `Request` and `Options` respectively. It seems that SQL Server was unable to find which index to use itself, because now it does the job correctly. But now the problem is other... I appended to the statement the clause `ORDER BY Priority, DateEntered`and even though there is an index on `(Priority, DateEntered) INCLUDE (RequestID)` on the `RequestTable`, Query2 returns no results again... What can be wrong this time? Please help me, since this is really important and I can't figure out an answer myself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There may be further requirements I'm not aware of, but when my code gets to a certain level of complexity I usually stand back and ask myself - could I do things simpler.

In this case, could you not run the query on just the Request table and store the values returned into a tablevar?

You'll probably need to set Transaction Isolation Level Serializable in order to get the row locking you desire. Not sure though - would need to try with and without.

```
 SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL SERIALIZABLE

 DECLARE @TempResults TABLE (RequestID int, Priority int, DateEntered DateTime)

 INSERT INTO @TempResults (RequestId, Priority, DateEntered)
 SELECT TOP 2 RequestId, Priority, DateEntered FROM Request WITH (ROWLOCK, UPDLOCK, READPAST) 
 ORDER BY Priority, DateEntered
```

Now with the rows locked join between the tablevar and the Options table to return the result-set you require.

```
 SELECT * FROM @TempResults Request INNER JOIN Options ON Request.RequestID = Options.RequestIDRef
```

I apologise if this isn't an option for you.