# Using (UPDLOCK, READPAST) and ORDER BY - Not Working?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, sql-order-by

I am trying to SELECT codes from my database, but I do not need another person coming along and selecting the same codes before I have a chance to update them with taken. I have tried using only updlock and this solves my duplicate sales problem BUT it adds the problem of deadlocks. So now I am using (UPDLOCK, READPAST), this works perfectly fine until I try to use an ORDER BY within my statement.

Microsoft SQL 2005

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION

SELECT Top 10 ID FROM dbo.CODES 
with (UPDLOCK, READPAST)
where ItemNo = 'type-2' AND Sold = 0 
order by cast(NowStamp as DateTime) ASC

COMMIT TRANSACTION
```

I feel like my problem is going to come from the indexes.

Comment: When I try to use ORDER BY in the transaction it is locking the entire table and not allowing the same transaction to run.

Answer (score 1):

This is a very similar issue to [ORDER BY and WITH(ROWLOCK, UPDLOCK, READPAST)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6388900/order-by-and-withrowlock-updlock-readpast)

The answer describes that you also need ROWLOCK and an index. Unfortunately, you can't create an index on that column since it's considered non-deterministic because of the CAST (see the first note on http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189292(v=sql.90).aspx).

You should use CONVERT and specify a deterministic style from: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928(v=sql.90).aspx