# Do i need ROWLOCK in addition to (UPDLOCK, READPAST) hints?

Tags: sql-server, locking, priority-queue, race-condition

I have a table of tasks. Multiple users simultaneously try to get a task. This trimmed query is the heart of my logic:

```
; WITH TASKS_CTE AS (
    SELECT TOP(1)   T.TASK_ID AS TASK_ID,
                    T.ASSIGNED_USER_CODE AS ASSIGNED_USER_CODE,
                    T.STATUS AS STATUS
    FROM TASK T WITH (ROWLOCK,READPAST)
    JOIN TASK_SCORE TS WITH (NOLOCK) ON TS.TASK_ID = T.TASK_ID
    WHERE
        T.STATUS = 0
    ORDER BY TS.TOTAL_SCORE DESC
)

UPDATE TASKS_CTE
SET STATUS = 1,
ASSIGNED_USER_CODE = @USER_CODE,
OUTPUT INSERTED.TASK_ID, INSERTED.ASSIGNED_USER_CODE, INSERTED.STATUS INTO @NEXT_TASK_TABLE;
```

I omitted the part where @@ROWCOUNT is checked to see if a task was successfully dequeued.

Well it turns out that `(ROWLOCK, READPAST)` is not preventing multiple users getting the same task. I came accross these two questions on SO, in [SQL Server Process Queue Race Condition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/939831/sql-server-process-queue-race-condition/940001#940001) it is advised that `(ROWLOCK, READPAST, UPDLOCK)` be specified. On the other hand, in [Using a database table as a queue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2177880/using-a-database-table-as-a-queue) `(UPDLOCK, READPAST)` is advised.

Hence my question, do i need to specify `ROWLOCK` in addition to `(UPDLOCK, READPAST)` in order to implement a multi-client queue? What exactly differs between `(UPDLOCK, READPAST)` and `(UPDLOCK, READPAST, ROWLOCK)`?

Answer (score 1):

The ROWLOCK is to ensure that the lock escalation is limited to only a single row.  This is what you want to help ensure your queue is processed in the correct order.  It would be a good practice in this example.

Comment: Yes i am aware UPDLOCK is missing, that code was my initial setup and turned out to be not working the way i assumed it would.