# mongoDB for distributed systems

Tags: mongodb, sharding

I am planning an application for an organization with remote locations where internet is not stable,
So I need a `NoSql` database, that can **read & write locally**, and **sync with central server** when online.

can `mongoDB sharding` be used with this scenario?

Comment: I think you need `Replica-Set` instead of `Sharding`, [Difference between Sharding And Replication on MongoDB](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/52632/56808)

Comment: @Soren `Replica-set` will not allow local writes, as I know.

Answer (score 1):

Better to ask: Why mongoDB sharding cannot be used with this scenario?

If you want to use local mongoDb clients to gather data queues you should understand the restrictions of such way.

Sharding is about effective data replication, not about local data gathering to send to server when internet is on, isn't it? Because shards are getting data from master instead of scenario when replica has more actual data than master? I would advise to use local private queues to gather user data when server and internet are not accessed by user client and send data from private queues when internet is on.

I think you can use mongoDb to save client information without internet alongside with any other Db or even any version control system :) But sharding it's not about it.

There are more information:

1. [Using a database table as a queue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2177880/using-a-database-table-as-a-queue)
2. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/biztalk/core/message-queuing-queues?redirectedfrom=MSDN
3. https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e11013/manage.htm#ADQUE2563