# How to update 2 tables row by row sequentially in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-update

I need to update two table in parallel based on each other data.

Below is the table structure for both tables.

**Product** table:

```
ProductId | ProductQuantity | Min Price | Max Price    
----------+-----------------+-----------+----------
1         | 122             | 58        | 585    
2         | 548             | 45        | 856
```

**Order** table:

```
Order ID | ProductID | ProductOrderQuantity |OfferPrice | OrderProcessDate | Status     
---------+-----------+----------------------+-----------+------------------+--------
1        | 2         |  35                  |  75       | Null             | Placed    
2        | 1         | 752                  | 258       | Null             | Placed
```

I need to update `Status` from `Order` table to "Confirm/Reject" in below condition:

1. `ProductOrderQuantity` should be less than `ProductQuantity` in the `Product` table
2. `OfferPrice` should be in between `Min Price` and `Max Price`
3. If both conditions match, then update `Status` in the `Order` table to `Confirm/Reject` and `OrderProcessDate` as the date on which it processed

This update should be done sequentially to each row from order table and once status from a row updates to "confirmed" immediately update `ProductQuantity` as `ProductQuantity - ProductOrderQuantity`

Comment: Forget about sequential / parallel concepts. If different records need to be consistent at the same time, you need to use a transaction.

Comment: Yes, But I need first row from order table should update then Product table. After this execution should come to second row from order table, then product table and it keeps going till last row of order table.

Comment: I'd recommend to search for "use table as a queue".  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2177880/using-a-database-table-as-a-queue https://rusanu.com/2010/03/26/using-tables-as-queues/  https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/20399/fifo-queue-table-for-multiple-workers-in-sql-server

Comment: You need to have a column that designates 'order'. At this stage it looks like `OrderId` right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was not able to test the code but the steps should be clear:

```
while 1 = 1
begin
  declare @OrderId int

  begin transaction

  select @OrderId = min(OrderId)
  from Order
  where Status = "Placed"

  if @@rowcount = 0
  begin
    /* Done with processing all orders */
    commit transaction
    break
  end

  update Order
  set Status = "Confirm"
  from Order o
  inner join Product p
  on p.ProductId = o.ProductId
  where o.OrderId = @OrderId
  and o.ProductOrderQuantity < p.ProductQuantity
  and o.OfferPrice between p.MinPrice and p.MaxPrice

  if @@rowcount = 1
  begin
    update Product
    set ProductQuantity = p.ProductQuantity - o.ProductOrderQuantity
    from Product p
    inner join Order o
    on p.ProductId = o.ProductId
    where o.OrderId = @OrderId

    commit transaction
  end
  else
  begin
    update Order
    set Status = "Reject"
    from Order o
    inner join Product p
    on p.ProductId = o.ProductId
    where o.OrderId = @OrderId

    commit transaction
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

You could check using

```
select 'OK'
FROM Order
INNER JOIN Product ON Product.ProductId = Order.ProductId
WHERE order.ProductOrderQuantity < Product.ProductQuantity
  AND order.OfferPrice between Product.min_price and Product.Max_price
```

And eventually You could try using a update in JOIN for check the condition

```
update Order 
SET status = "Confirm/Reject",
    OrderProcessDate =  GETDATE()
FROM Order
INNER JOIN Product ON Product.ProductId = Order.ProductId
WHERE order.ProductOrderQuantity < Product.ProductQuantity
  AND order.OfferPrice between Product.min_price and Product.Max_price
```

Comment: Thanks scaisEdge. In above query how Product Table will update? Condition define in last line of my question.

Comment: If you set an order id adding a where condition the updated  should involve all the rows  with valid condition for the order..

Answer (score 0):

I assume that the orders are sorted by `OrderId`. That means, the lower the order, the higher the priority.

See the following code, I think it will help you

```
CREATE TABLE #OrderJobDispatch(
  OrderId BIGINT
)

DECLARE @orderID BIGINT;

INSERT INTO #OrderJobDispatch (OrderId)
SELECT OrderId
FROM
  [Order]
WHERE
  Status = 'Placed'

WHILE EXISTS(SELECT * FROM #OrderJobDispatch)
BEGIN
  -- take the highest priority order
  SET @orderId = SELECT TOP(1) OrderId FROM #OrderJobDispatch ORDER BY OrderId

  -- update Order table if the condition matches
  UPDATE o
  SET o.Status = 'Confirm/Reject'
  FROM
    [Order] AS o
  INNER JOIN
    [Product] AS p
  ON
    o.ProductId = p.ProductId
  WHERE
    o.OrderId = @orderId
  AND
    o.ProductOrderQuantity < p.ProductQuantity
  AND 
    o.OfferPrice BETWEEN p.MinPrice AND p.MaxPrice

  -- update Product table if it is appropriate
  UPDATE p
  SET ProductQuantity = p.ProductQuantity - o.ProductOrderQuantity 
  FROM 
    [Product] AS p
  INNER JOIN
    [Order] AS o
  ON
    p.ProductId = o.ProductId
  WHERE
    o.OrderId = @orderId
  AND
    o.Status = 'Confirm/Reject'

  DELETE FROM #OrderJobDispatch
  WHERE OrderId = @orderId
END
```

Here, we are actually using `#OrderJobDispatch` table like a Queue. While there is a single row in that queue-like table, we are doing operations using `OrderId`.